# Two identities involving Gregory coefficients and different arithmetic functions from an integral representation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

This morning I've deduced two identities that involve Gregory coefficients $G_n$ invoking the so-called Schröder's integral formula (this is the [Wikipedia's article for Gregory coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients)).

The first is $$\frac{1}{\varphi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty|G_n|\frac{F_n}{\varphi^n}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+x}{(1+x)^2\varphi^2-(1+x)\varphi-1}\cdot\frac{dx}{\pi^2+\log^2 x},\tag{1}$$
where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio and $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers (with the standard definition), and this second identity that I believe that holds for reals $|y|<1$ was

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)\frac{G_k}{k}\cdot\frac{y^{kn}}{1-y^{kn}}=\int_0^\infty\log\left(1+\frac{y}{1+x}\right)\cdot\frac{dx}{\pi^2+\log^2 x},\tag{2}$$
where $\mu(n)$ denotes the Möbius function and the resulting identity is also a combination with the Lambert series for the Möbius funciton (a combination , with Schröder's integral formula).

My numerical check of such identities was very poor, and my doubt is that to create $(1)$ and $(2)$ I've swapped the  summation that is implicit and the integral in each *RHS* of such identities.

> **Question.** I think that the corresponding *RHS* of each/both equations can be justified using the dominated convergence theorem (or absolute convergence). Am I right? **Many thanks.**

If you detect numerically that some identity is false, please add such evidence.

Comment: Does (1) only work for $\phi$ or can we substitute some other number instead? (My doubt is because we have $\phi$ on both sides)

Comment: The original series that I wrote was

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|G_n|\frac{F_n}{\varphi^n}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\varphi(1+x)}{(1+x)^2\varphi^2-(1+x)\varphi-1}\cdot\frac{dx}{\pi^2+\log^2 x}$$

where in *RHS* I've used the closed-sum of a *generating series* (alternating in signs) related to Fibonacci numbers. That is why is required to involve the golden ratio (due the convergence radius of the mentioned generating series). Many thanks for your attention @YuriyS  I hope that my calculations were rights.